# jQuery .fadeToggle hidden element when clicked outside element or matching elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

[image]

I'm using jQuery .fadeToggle for a hidden element ".card-overlay" that is being used as share widget within a grid item, as shown in the uploaded image it's display whenever the element ".open-card-menu" is clicked. It's working but not the way I'd like it to.

**How it should work**

- Only one share widget should be open at a time.
- Share widget should hide when clicked outside of element.

**Basic HTML mark up**

```
<!-- Parent -->
<div class="card-wrap">

  <div class="card-bottom">

    <div class="post-info">

      <ul class="card-icons">

        <li>
          <!--Click Element -->
          <div class="card-items open-card-menu">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Share overlay-->
  <div id="overlayMenu" class="card-overlay">
  </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( ".open-card-menu" ).click(function() {       
    $( this ).closest(".card-wrap").find(".card-overlay").fadeToggle();
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: And could you provide us a fiddle?